# Dynamic forms not dynamic while creating or editing a record?

Tags: dynamic-forms

I have converted a page layout of a custom object to a dynamic form. I have made a section conditionally visible, depending on a check box (elsewhere on the form) being true/false.

I notice that while creating or editing a record, changing the checkbox value does not make the section visible or invisible. The section is visible or invisible, depending on what the value of the checkbox was when starting the create/edit session.

It is possible to make a dynamic form also dynamic while creating/editing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields are naturally reactive, but you have to click away from the input box, for example, if let's say I have two fields:

1. Company Name
2. Amount

and I am now putting in a visibility filter to show the Company Name field, only if the Amount field is equals to 1000.

Now let's say if I am editing the record, and the default Amount is 1000. If I change the Amount field, to 900 (just an example, can be any number in this case); the Company Name field won't disspear immediately, but only when I click away from this Amount field (whitespace out of the input box/another field).

However, **answering your** **main question** regarding, Dynamic form visibility filter on **Sections** are not being dynamic. I have personally tested it on Standard object, it (Section) is not dynamic/reactive. I found that it has been posted on [Salesforce's IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZDcUAN/allow-field-sections-to-appear-real-time-dynamic-forms).

One workaround seem to "**manually set visibility filter for each of the fields under the Section**" - [From the same resource linked above](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdZDcUAN/allow-field-sections-to-appear-real-time-dynamic-forms).